# Matplotlib .plot() doesn't print all data points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've created some data in a list of lists and now I am trying to plot them all in a line graph using .plot from matplotlib. I have 6 groups and for each group I have one data point per year for 10 years. I want to plot all 6 of these groups over time on one line plot.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import StrMethodFormatter


group_data = [[0.019661816751867872, 0.02043028685790527, 0.02023318156674184, 0.017430534194606787, 0.019330407797782608, 0.01969285217721039, 0.020037761795104064, 0.02195322742933805, 0.02104150568005187, 0.023173911874613543],
            [0.046087298466378296, 0.04628085390260173, 0.04816816305689119, 0.05218907002973444, 0.060561320045386814, 0.0625292296024774, 0.0604625274209567, 0.05977172708885976, 0.05898549566113317, 0.06442723875581365],
            [0.015257569799449469, 0.01667778519012675, 0.017148206459299604, 0.015841279606274992, 0.01711575004442986, 0.01660873412121595, 0.01645803092974778, 0.019442835218668374, 0.02056187659321236, 0.019746216092695647],
            [0.1048368069209595, 0.1054869913275517, 0.10197438406876304, 0.0988584708978434, 0.0944373812355603, 0.09515262592428743, 0.09366234843441344, 0.09388053785407202, 0.09037455478874115, 0.0906121461408178],
            [0.1048368069209595, 0.1054869913275517, 0.10197438406876304, 0.0988584708978434, 0.0944373812355603, 0.09515262592428743, 0.09366234843441344, 0.09388053785407202, 0.09037455478874115, 0.0906121461408178],
            [0.1048368069209595, 0.1054869913275517, 0.10197438406876304, 0.0988584708978434, 0.0944373812355603, 0.09515262592428743, 0.09366234843441344, 0.09388053785407202, 0.09037455478874115, 0.0906121461408178]]

years = ['2008','2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017']


plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Percentage')

plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0%}'))    #formats y axis as %

plt.plot(years, group_data[0], label='Group 1')
plt.plot(years, group_data[1], label='Group 2')
plt.plot(years, group_data[2], label='Group 3')
plt.plot(years, group_data[3], label='Group 4')
plt.plot(years, group_data[4], label='Group 5')
plt.plot(years, group_data[5], label='Group 6')

plt.legend()
```

When I run the code, my results look like this:

[image]

I don't understand why. There are only 4 lines instead of 6. Group 4 and 5 have mysteriously disappeared.

However, I was trying to troubleshoot this and if I plot only the first 4 groups:

```
plt.plot(years, group_data[0], label='Group 1')
plt.plot(years, group_data[1], label='Group 2')
plt.plot(years, group_data[2], label='Group 3')
plt.plot(years, group_data[3], label='Group 4')

plt.legend()
```

Everything appears to be correct:

[image]

If I plot just the last two groups:

```
plt.plot(years, group_data[4], label='Group 5')
plt.plot(years, group_data[5], label='Group 6')

plt.legend()
```

I only get one line:

[image]

I am plotting the 'group_data' object. I have verified that all objects in group_data are the same length (10). All the numbers in those lists are of the same data type.

What is happening? Why can I only plot 4 lines and seemingly 2 of them dissappear?

Comment: Groups 4-6 are identical.

Comment: Therefore they are covering each other up. Try dashing one of them

Comment: I would really avoid copy-pasting and write instead: `for n in range(6):` `plt.plot(years, group_data[n], label=f'Group {n+1}')`.